# Execute python script on user's computer (web application)

Tags: python, php, windows, ldap, wamp

I'm developing a web application (PHP) where I need to get user's windows ID (to auth the user with LDAP). I've found that with python I can easily get it with the following script :

```
import os
print(os.getenv('username'))
```

Which return 'firestname.lastname'

The problem is that, when I call it in my application with :

```
$python = "C:\Python3.8\python.exe";
$pyscript = "C:\wamp64\www\Dashboard\Content\python\simple.py";
$cmd = "$python $pyscript";
exec($cmd, $output);
```

I got my computer name : 'MY-COMPUTER$'

I guess the script is running on my local webserver (wamp64). So my question is :

1) Can I execute this script on the user's computer ? And if I can, shall I have python installed on their PC ?
2) Do you have any other solution ?

Thanks !

Comment: 1) no 2) Javascript

Comment: Ty for your response but on others posts, they say it's not possible due to security issues ... Maybe I missed something ?

Comment: May I ask what you need the username for?

Comment: To avoid to have a login / password for the application (when we have LDAP server) ... Moreover, I need to know who is connected on the application to give access rights on pages.

Comment: This is not how you do single singon. It would be **completely** unsafe.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the username of a user authenticated to a windows domain controller of a company for SingleSignOn?

If so, you should look into ntlm authentication and GSSAPI.

Which webserver software are you using?